# Геолокация для декстоп приложения

Tags: c#, .net, геолокация

Гео локация доступна только для смартфон приложений, есть ли какая нибудь сторонняя библиотека для определения или Web API для определения местоположения приложения?

Comment: Вроде, по документации, Geolocator доступен и в декстоп приложениях https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.geolocation.geolocator.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
   using System.Device.Location; 
   class Geo
    {

        public double x, y, z;
        public Geo()
        {
            GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
            watcher.MovementThreshold = 1.0;
            watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0));
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            if (watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown == false)
            {
                GeoCoordinate coor = watcher.Position.Location;
                x = coor.Latitude;
                y = coor.Longitude;
                z = coor.Altitude;
            }
        }
    }
```

Попробовал написать свой класс попроще, всё работает

Answer (score 0):

Данный код работает даже если нету доступа к GPS данным, определяет по IP адрессу, данным от Wi-Fi.

```
public class ImmediateLocation : IDisposable
{
    private GeoCoordinateWatcher _watcher;
    private Action<GeoCoordinate> _action;

    public ImmediateLocation(Action<GeoCoordinate> a)
    {
        Debug.Assert(a != null);

        _action = a;
    }

    public void GetLocation()
    {
        if (_watcher == null)
        {
            _watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.Default);
            _watcher.MovementThreshold = 1000;

            _watcher.PositionChanged += new 
                EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>
                (_watcher_PositionChanged);
            _watcher.StatusChanged += new 
                EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>
                (_watcher_StatusChanged);

            _watcher.Start(false);

            if (_watcher.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled
                || _watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Denied)
                Dispose();
        }
    }

    void _watcher_StatusChanged(object sender, 
        GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GeoPositionStatus.Disabled 
            || _watcher.Permission == GeoPositionPermission.Denied)
            Dispose();
    }

    void _watcher_PositionChanged(object sender, 
        GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        _action(e.Position.Location);
        Dispose();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_watcher != null)
        {
            _watcher.Stop();
            _watcher.PositionChanged -= new 
                EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>
                (_watcher_PositionChanged);
            _watcher.StatusChanged -= new 
                EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>
                (_watcher_StatusChanged);
            _watcher.Dispose();
        }
        _watcher = null;
        _action = null;
    }
}
```

Пример использования:

```
var immediate = new ImmediateLocation(x => location = x);
immediate.GetLocation();

GeoCoordinate location;
```

Если вам не нужна высокая точность, то можно воспользоваться вебсервисом, например:

```
public class IpProperties
    {
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string Region { get; set; }
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public string Lat { get; set; }
        public string Lon { get; set; }
        public string TimeZone { get; set; }
        public string ISP { get; set; }
        public string ORG { get; set; }
        public string AS { get; set; }
        public string Query { get; set; }
    }
 public string IPRequestHelper(string url)
    {
        HttpWebRequest objRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpWebResponse objResponse = (HttpWebResponse)objRequest.GetResponse();

        StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(objResponse.GetResponseStream());
        string responseRead = responseStream.ReadToEnd();

        responseStream.Close();
        responseStream.Dispose();

        return responseRead;
    }

    public IpProperties GetCountryByIP(string ipAddress)
    {
        string ipResponse = IPRequestHelper("http://ip-api.com/xml/" + ipAddress);
        using (TextReader sr = new StringReader(ipResponse))
        {
            using (System.Data.DataSet dataBase = new System.Data.DataSet())
            {
                IpProperties ipProperties = new IpProperties();
                dataBase.ReadXml(sr);
                ipProperties.Status = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
                ipProperties.Country = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][1].ToString();
                ipProperties.CountryCode = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][2].ToString();
                ipProperties.Region = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][3].ToString();
                ipProperties.RegionName = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][4].ToString();
                ipProperties.City = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][5].ToString();
                ipProperties.Zip = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][6].ToString();
                ipProperties.Lat = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][7].ToString();
                ipProperties.Lon = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][8].ToString();
                ipProperties.TimeZone = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][9].ToString();
                ipProperties.ISP = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][10].ToString();
                ipProperties.ORG = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][11].ToString();
                ipProperties.AS = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][12].ToString();
                ipProperties.Query = dataBase.Tables[0].Rows[0][13].ToString();

                return ipProperties;
            }
        }
    }
```

Если вам нужна эта инфа для веб ресурса, то можно сделать на js'e вот так:

```
function getLocation()
{
    if (navigator.geolocation)
    {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
     }
}

function showPosition(position)
{
      console.log("Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
  "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude); 
}
```

Comment: переменная по имени coord постоянно имеет значение Uknown

Comment: @Алексей я обновил пример. Попробуйте, заодно обратите внимание на статусы.

Comment: я уже просто скопипастил ваш пример и статус не меняется uknown