# Как определить координаты телефона в приложении на c#?

Tags: c#, google-maps, gps

В приложении на c#, где используется библиотека GMap.net, необходимо добавить функцию отслеживания местонахождения человека на карте, по номеру телефона, т.е. чтобы в приложение через определенные моменты времени поступали координаты, где находится тот или иной телефон. Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать? Если возможно, поделитесь ссылками.

Comment: насколько мне известно, то надо отправлять сигнал на телефонную станцию или спутинк, чтобы он нашел этот номер, потом на другую телефонную станцию, а она уже и будет показывать координаты абонента, хотя мб я и ошибаюсь, но думаю что вот так работает эта штука

Comment: т.е. вы хотите по введенному номеру телефона определить его положение не спрашивая хозяина телефона? Мило, многие этого хотят, но могут только избранные. Если телефон сам не сообщает о своем местоположении - считайте что это невозможно, если конечно вы не являетесь сотрудником оператора мобильной связи или спец-служб.

Comment: Почему, не спрашивая? С согласия хозяина телефона. Нужно понять сам принцип и как это программно описать.

Comment: тогда вам потребуется сервис сбора и обработки данных, мобильный клиент к этому сервису, для отправки данных о текущем местоположении с зарегистрированного в вашей системе телефона и приложение для просмотра собранных данных. Что из этого уже есть или знаете как сделать?

Comment: Пока не знаю, буду думать...

Comment: Похоже автору ответ не понравился, вопрос нужно дополнить дополнительными сведеньями, пояснить почему не нравится ответ, как именно передаются координаты, откуда и куда. Возможно у автора, на с# написано приложение для телефона. Возможно хостится страница. Плюс автор давно не появлялся.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще можете посмотреть в сторону `JavaScript` и [API Geolocation](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=32&id=2723), а так же [gmaps.js](https://habrahabr.ru/post/145152/). Если же нужно решение конкретно под С#, то я думаю нужно смотреть в уже созданных темах, [например](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/468334/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BF-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

Answer (score 0):

1. Делаешь приложение на телефон, которое пользователь устанавливает и которому даёт разрешение на доступ к геолокации.
2. Приложение периодически присылает текущие координаты на твой сервер.
3. Приложение на C# периодически спрашивает у твоего сервера координаты.